# ¿Cómo codificar una URL absoluta en C# sin usar la clase HttpServerUtility y clases relacionadas?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Estoy desarrollando una solución Sandbox para SharePoint Online<sup>1</sup> que recibe como parámetro de configuración una URL absoluta:

Ejemplo de URL absoluta:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86477/does-c-sharp-have-an-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent

Debido a la limitaciones nativas de las soluciones Sandbox, estoy buscando una manera nativa en C# para **codificar una URL absoluta en C# sin usar la clase HttpServerUtility y clases relacionadas** (sin usar dependencias de librerías de SharePoint u otras clases que puedan no estar disponibles por el tipo de solución Sandbox).

---

<sup>1</sup> *Esta versión de SharePoint admite soluciones Add-ins y Sandbox("esta última se encuentra sin soporte de Microsoft desde la introducción de las Add-ins o también llamadas Apps").*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¿Manera Nativa en c#?, debes estar equivocado, cuando uno desarrolla en SharePoint con c# ya deja de ser un desarrollo nativo puesto estas agregando código y esto no es nativo.

Una solución nativa implica una minoría de código, por ejemplo desplegar una lista por medio de definiciones (xml) y esquemas (schemas), todo se puede hacer totalmente declarativo (definiciones/squemas).

Ahora cuando dices que buscas una manera nativa para codificar las url con C# hago de cuenta que te refieres a utilizar en su máxima expresión las utilidades que SharePoint proporciona. Asi que te recomiendo y utilizar [SPEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spencode.aspx).

> [SPEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spencode.aspx) Proporciona métodos para codificar cadenas.

Aqui un ejemplo de como codificar una cadena url:

```
SPEncode.UrlEncode("http://msdn.microsoft.com")
```

La salida sería:

`http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn%2Emicrosoft%2Ecom`

Aqui estan todos los metodos que puedes utilizar:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spencode_methods.aspx

Para saber mas de las restricciones sandbox puedes echar un ojo aquí:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff872402(v=office.14).aspx#InsideSP14_Ch4_USR

Comment: Creo que el OP se refería a maneras nativas como formas de lograr lo que quiere sin usar librerías externas, usando solo las que le ofrece el framework y que pueda usar en el entorno de sandbox. La primera parte de tu respuesta *"sobra"*

Comment: Supuse eso, por eso en el tercer párrafo hago de cuenta que eso esta suponiendo, ademas me pareció importante mencionar todo lo que escribí en los dos primeros párrafos, actualmente hay mucha confusión sobre esto. Saludos! :)

Comment: @JhonAlx, tiene razón en cuanto a que me refiero a `usar lo que tiene disponible el framework`, no me supe expresar bien. Una respuesta completa ha ofrecido @Andres Felipe Williams Suarez. también "por expandir mi inquietud" publiqué la misma pregunta y obtuve una respuesta diferente a las mencionadas aquí. He usado antes `SPEncode`, pero honestamente había olvidado aquella clase. gracias a todos.

Comment: Con gusto estamos para ayudarnos! :)

Answer (score 2):

Siempre esta la alternativa de hacerlo manualmente :) [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IrI0jr)

```
public static string urlEncode(string source)
{
    var fixture = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToList();
    return string.Join("", source.Select(c => fixture.Contains(c) ? 
            c.ToString() : "%" + Convert.ToByte(c).ToString("x2"))).Replace("%20", "+");
}

var urlencoded = urlEncode("http://stackoverflow.com/text?a es b");
```

Salida:

```
http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow%2ecom%2ftext%3fa+es+b
```

Comment: +1 por una alternativa usando código solamente; es decir: `código personalizado` :) .

Comment: Es completamente válida, pero no es lo que se quiere, en la pregunta se dice que se requiere ``usar lo que tiene disponible el framework`` o mejor aun, ``usar lo que tiene disponible el SDK de SharePoint``. Saludos :) !

Comment: esta solución aplica en ambos casos, aunque me parece mejor tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas algo que sea parte del framework (y no usar `HttpServerUtility`), puedes usar `WebUtility`, que es parte del espacio de nombres `System.Net` (en `System.dll`): https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-xl/library/system.net.webutility.aspx

Comment: no es buena practica, cuando se trabaja con SharePoint es preferible utilizar todos los objetos que SharePoint nos provee, tengamos en cuenta que SharePoint es una caja negra, tu le dices la operación y ella se encarga de hacer eso y muchas cosas mas, cuando saltas esa caja negra y pasas directo al Framework estas omitiendo todo ese proceso que hace adentro la caja negra. **Vuelvo y repito** tu respuesta es valida por que funcionara, pero no es buena practica. Saludos :) !